# How create a 2-second pause for each formula added in a Auto Fill Down created via Google Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, custom-function

I have a custom function to send messages to Telegram from values that are in the cells of my table.

With Auto Fill Down created at the same time, Telegram warns that it has hit the simultaneous sending limit when there are many different cells with values, so I need to find a way to add a 2 second pause for each formula that is added in the cells and do not create a queue for sending.

My script currently looks like this:

```
  var sheetName = "Sheet4";
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = sss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  sheet.getRange('AB1').setFormula('=IF(Z1="","",EnviarTelegram($AA$1,$AA$2,URLredirect(U1),Z1))');
  var lr = sheet.getLastRow();
  var fillDownRange = sheet.getRange(1, 28, lr);
  sheet.getRange('AB1').copyTo(fillDownRange);
```

> Example of my need:

Formula added in `AB1`
`=IF(Z1="","",EnviarTelegram($AA$1,$AA$2,URLredirect(U1),Z1))`

*2 second pause*

Formula added in `AB2`
`=IF(Z2="","",EnviarTelegram($AA$1,$AA$2,URLredirect(U2),Z2))`

*2 second pause*

Formula added in `AB3`
`=IF(Z3="","",EnviarTelegram($AA$1,$AA$2,URLredirect(U3),Z3))`

And so on...

Comment: If you plan on using Utilities.sleep() then also plan on using SpreadsheetApp.flush() immediately prior to it too insure that each formula makes it to the spreadsheet because using along Utilities.sleep() tends to freeze all actions during the sleep.  In fact using only spreadsheetApp.flush may actually be enough of a delay by itself.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Cooper, but if in the case of the ```copyTo(fillDownRange)``` it sends the formulas to the cells all at once, what should I adjust in the script so that there is this addition time in each cell? Could you help me in this regard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to build the entire script for you because if I do then you will never learn how to do it by yourself.  But this is the basic idea

```
const formulas=['formula1','formula2',....];
const ranges=['range1','range2',....];//you will have to figure out how to do this
formulas.forEach((f,i)=>{
  ranges[i].setFormula(f);
  spreadsheetApp.flush();
  Utilities.sleep(delay in milliseconds);
});
```

Obvious you need to be aware of your quota limits on script time with regard to running such a function with many array elements.  Not intended to be an exact answer.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a pause to add formulas with a custom function is not a good idea because those formulas will be recalculated when the spreadsheet be opened and also when the custom function parameters change.

Instead, create a function that call the custom function providing it with the corresponding parameters.